# Flex actionscript: how can I export my function to other SWF?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I want to export some of my functions to external so that other people can embed my SWF into their's and invoke the function, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [LocalConnection](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) class for that.

Here is an example: http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Local+Connections

Comment: Is there a way to use SWFLoader and invoke the method directly?